# Make a copy / clone of an active object in ruby, and make changes to it, without messing with the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-objects

I am new to ruby. I've coded in many languages, and normally get things quickly if there is a good reference and things are explained logically. I am going out of my mind. I've looked at every possible question related to this on stackoverflow, as well as on other websites. Everybody says use .clone or .dub or freeze and even something like Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr)) but none of those work.

I just want a copy of the original object, that I can modify at runtime, without it making any changes to the database.

The rails project loads a bunch of products into an object, which is then injected into a dropdown. Let's say it's called @products. The client wants me to remove certain entries from being displayed in the dropdown, but they must NOT be removed from the database.

In php for instance, you would just load the db object into a variable, and delete what you do not want by id for instance, and then loop through the resulting object / array and that creates the drop down. This makes NO alteration to the database.

I realized very quickly, Ruby does not work like that, and it deletes things direct from the database, even if I use .clone or .dup.

Let's say I use tempproducts = @products, and I do something like tempproducts.delete(11) , I don't want the system to go and delete @products(11) as well.

This is an elementary function of programming, why can't I figure out to do something as simple as this?

Thanks kindly to anybody that can help me out with this, or even post a link to the correct answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method to filter collection of records

e.g Let's say your `Product` model has one column `shipping_category` and you want to show only product with `local` and `zonal` shipping categories then it will look like

`@product.select { |p| p.shipping_category == 'local' || shipping_category == 'zonal'  }`

Ideally you should use https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html to filter data based on some condition at DB level use `where` method of Active Record.

Comment: Thanks. This is a project I inherited from another developer. Instead of making the change inside the view, I went back to the controller where I used xxx.where('id = ?', to filter the product by id. Your answer should also work, and I will go and test it. It is closer to what I intended to do than what I did to solve the issue.